# Problems with "Pro Business Applications with Silverlight 4"

Tags: sql-server-2008-express, adventureworks

I'm having problems setting up the database described in Apress's **Pro Business Applications with Silverlight 4**.  I have SQL Server 2008 R2 Express which doesn't support Full Text Search, and I can't install the database from [codeplex](http://msftdbprodsamples.codeplex.com/) (AdventureWorks2008 OLTP) because it requires Full Text Search.  The book suggests getting this exact version of SQL Server (Express and everything).  I'm just wondering if anyone knows of a way to install a database into SQL Server when a feature is not provided.  Is there anything else I can do.  I'm stuck for the time being.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SQL Server 2008 R2 Express with Advanced Services supports full text searching - you probably don't have that version.

http://www.microsoft.com/express/Database/InstallOptions.aspx

Comment: I tried this, I am using Windows 7 which gives me an incompatibility error.  I'm thinking its telling me that I just need to install SP2.

Comment: I was using an older version of "SQL Server 2008 R2 Express with Advanced Services".  I used your link, and it worked fine.